# Problem with comparing a value to a specific object of an ArrayList Java

Tags: java

I have the class Student with a constructor that sets the values int s_code, String name and int age.

When I create an object of the class Student I pass it into an ArrayList AllStudents.

My problem is that I want the user to enter an Id and check if there is that Id in the ArrayList. If its not let him add a new student else tell him to try again.

I tried to loop through the ArrayList with for and inside of it
I have an if statement with .contains and if it is true I have a simple println("Good") just to test it.

When I run my program though it skips it.

Here is my code:

```
static ArrayList<Student> AllStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
static void InitStudents() //this is a method that creates some students when I call it in main.
{
    AllStudents.add(new Student(1,"James",15));
    AllStudents.add(new Student(2,"John",16));
    AllStudents.add(new Student(3,"Rose",15));

}


System.out.println("Enter the ID of the student you want to add.");
            Scanner get_new_code = new Scanner(System.in);
            int s_code = get_new_code.nextInt();



for(Student code : AllStudents) 
{
     if (AllStudents.contains(s_code)) //I think that I have to include age and name for it to work.
     {
        System.out.println("Good");
     }       
}
```

By the way sorry if I didn't explain something or I did something completely wrong I'm new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That advanced loop is not helping you in the way you implemented it.

```
for(Student code : AllStudents){          //"code" is one element out of the list
    if (AllStudents.contains(s_code)){    //here you are checking the whole list
        System.out.println("Good");
    }       
}
```

This might be what you are looking for:

```
for(Student code : AllStudents){       
    if(code.getSCode() == s_code){       //here the one element named "code",
                                         //out of the list, will be checked
        System.out.println("Good");
    }       
}
```

A getter method (this one is called for example getSCode()) will help you here, to ask for every attribute of a student object. It will return the s_code of the object you are looking at.

EDIT AS EXAMPLE:

```
public class Student{
    int s_code;
    String name;
    int age;

    public Student(int code, String name, int age){
        this.s_code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getSCode(){
        return s_code;
    }

    public int setSCode(int newSCode){
        this.s_code = newSCode;
    }    
}
```

With the getter and setter you can ask for data of an object or you can set the data.

Comment: Ok now I understad it better cause when I was searching                          I found something similar but I didn't understand it.
But when I type code.getSCode() I get the error cannot find symbol 
And if I'm not wrong this happens when I dont init a variable
But here we init code as a Student 
No?

Comment: You have to implement getter and setter methods in your class. That are "helper"-methods, that will give or set variables in objects. In your student class you have to declare the method like this: public int getSCode(){return s_code;}   You can call that method of an object from anywhere and it will return the s_code you assigned to that object. In your case a student object.

Comment: Oh that was my fault. I was declaring getSCode in my main class not Student.
Thank you very much for the explanation and for being patient with me cause I'm new.
It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`AllStudents` contains students and s_code is an int.

You can search by id mapping it first. Assuming the code is in a field called Id.

```
 allStudents.stream().map(s -> Student::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(s_code);
```